# Does angular momentum change what I change center of mass?

Tags: angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

So recently I've noticed some discrepancies in my physics simulation, and these occur when I add/remove particles from a rigid body. Strange things like things flying to the sky constantly occur, and I think it has to do with the changing of the center of mass.

Could this have something to do with the center of mass changing? I know that you have to offset the position of an object when you change Center of Mass, is something similar required with Angular Momentum as well?

Comment: This is completely impossible to answer without knowing the numerical details of your simulation/what you mean. The center of mass is $\frac{1}{M}\sum_i m_i \vec{r}_i$, and this changes if you add another $m_i$ and another $\vec{r}_i$. The angular momentum is $\sum m_i \vec{r}_i\times\vec{v}_i$, and this will change if the particle you add has nonzero velocity. But "you have to offset the x,y,z of an object when you change center of mass" is a totally nonsensical statement. It may make perfect sense in the context of *your* physics simulation, but it's completely meaningless to the rest of us!

Comment: Alright, I changed it just to 'position', I guess XYZ was a little vague

Comment: That's not really the problem. We don't know how your physics engine works, if it's force based, impulse based, etc. We don't know why you even need to know the center of mass of an object, or its angular momentum, or what you could be doing with those quantities. Besides, most physicists aren't the best people to ask if you're trying to write a real-time physics engine (if you have 100 bodies interacting, a physicist might tell you to solve a $100^2$ size matrix equation each frame, whereas a game developer would tell you to use a lightning fast "good enough" approach).

Answer (score 1):

Moment of Inertia of a rigid body is a function of both *mass* and *distribution* of mass. As you change the *center of mass*, you should expect to see a change in the moment of inertia which would result in a different *angular momentum*.

Comment: Crap, what do I have to do to get the Angular Momentum after adding/removing a particle (changing MOI). I've looked everywhere for this and I can't find a solution, most games don't change MOI dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding" a particle?  You can't use conservation of momentum (linear or angular) when mass isn't constant.  If you calculate the angular momentum of the particle that arrives, then the sum of all the momenta is conserved.

Comment: Well the particle is initially at rest Before I attach it to the rigid body. So would it be correct to calculate the force needed to move that particle, then subtract that force from the body?

Comment: @thebest108, forces aren't momenta.  If the forces come from the body itself (they latch together), then the momentum is still conserved.  If you're using an external force to attach it, then momentum isn't conserved.

Answer (score 0):

How we normally define  angular momentum of a particle or a system of particles about a point or a fixed axis passing through that point ?

The angular momentum is defined as moment of particle's momentum L= **r x p** .

For an arrangement of particles  these momenta are added vectorially to get the total angular momentum .

The individual  moment is taken from an axis /or a fixed  point defined before starting the calculation of angular momentum.

So if   a particle is added or subtracted from a system of particles  the total angular momentum  of a system  would change .

Therefore when  one changes the center of mass i.e. you are changing the distribution of particles/bodies your angular momentum should change.

Answer (score 0):

Moment of inertia is not just a concept of rigid bodies.  All systems exhibit the concept of moment of inertia around their center of mass.  However, for a game purpose, measuring moments of inertia for a rigid body happens to be a very convenient thing to do because the rigid body constrains the solutions, so often inertia and moment of inertia are all you need to fully calculate the position and orientation of the object.

Thus, to do it properly, you need to combine particles into a rigid body by looking at the center of mass and moment of inertia of the system of the rigid body and the new particle.  By the laws of physics, you will *always* conserve angular momentum around any combined center of mass, but this particular one is about to become important because it's about to become the new center of mass of a new rigid body.

That all being said, as a programmer, I'm probably 95% certain that objects flying into the air is a programming error.  That is to say, if I were the one programming this, and objects were flying into the air, it'd be a logic bug.